# Using request/request to post file from the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node.JS project with a server-side and a client-side powered by webpack. I was hoping to convert my project from a combination of `axios`/`request` to just use `request`, but I'm having issues doing file uploads from the browser. I'm using the `request-promise` library, but I have the same issue whether I'm using `request` or `request-promise`. My attempt is to do this:

```
return request.post({
  uri: `${BASE_URL}/files`,
  formData: {
    token: token,
    file: {value: filedata, options: {filename: filename}}
  }
})
```

where `filedata` is a `File` object returned from using an `input` tag to find a file on the user's computer. The error I get is:

```
TypeError: self._form.on is not a function
```

This seems to be because `formData` requires a readable stream from something like `fs`. How do I get the correct input to `request`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this required a non-trivial solution to finally get working. I used a `FileReader` to convert the `File` object I received from the form into an `ArrayBuffer`. I manually set the headers to 'multipart/form-data' and used the `multipart` property to set up all my content. Finally, I needed this to all be wrapped in a `Promise`, so I had to set up the object and call resolve appropriately.

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  const fr = new FileReader()
  fr.onload = (event) => {
    return request({
      uri: `${BASE_URL}/files`,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
      multipart: {
        chunked: false,
        data: [
          {
            'Content-Disposition': 'form-data; name="token"',
            body: token
          },
          {
            'Content-Disposition': `form-data; name="file"; `filename="${filename}"`}`,
            body: event.target.result
          }
        ]
      }
    }).then(resolve)
  }
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(filedata)
})
```

Comment: Gosh! reading the hole file into memory is no good, what if they upload 200+ mb or something. just use FormData and the promisified fetch api

Answer (score 1):

add header in post request also, this will help to send your file with stream as you looking for.

```
return request.post({
  uri: `${BASE_URL}/files`,
  formData: {
    token: token,
    file: {value: filedata, options: {filename: filename}}
  },
  headers: {'enctype': 'multipart/form-data'}
})
```